# Is there any IDE that support “return type deduction” in gcc 4.8（C++1y/C++14） and autocomplete for it？

Tags: c++, autocomplete, ide, c++14, return-type-deduction

Like

```
auto test(){
     string a= "123";
     return a;
}
....
test().<autocomplete>
```

I found that Netbeans 7.4 and Eclipse 4.2 didn't support this feature yet.

Comment: I would really doubt it. This will probably take a good long while after C++14 is published.

Comment: In a year, probably MSVS.

Comment: Additionally, return type deduction is a feature that I would avoid if possible. The semantics are a bit awkward, the compiler needs to see the *definition* of the function, not just a declaration, if it is a template it needs to instantiate it (inhibiting uses in SFINAE contexts), in the implementation of the function you need to be careful as of what you are returning, etc...

Comment: are you talking about this: http://i.imgur.com/1pHr6H7.png. Generally I have anything that's on clang tip of trunk available for me for completion on VIM.

Comment: also QtCreator has a [wip/clang branch](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/source/9f831dde07cb2411808534e76669b28a1b76e21d:) which probably should support this using the correct clang version. As Xcode also uses clang for completion (I think), it should support this soon, if not already.

Comment: with QtCreator and vim at my disposal, I would never use Netbeans nor Eclipse except by brute force.